# Confused about prestashop PDF generated process. Where is the code to handle the logic?

Tags: prestashop, tcpdf, prestashop-1.6

I want to deep understand prestahop inside structure and amend some parts. I am stoped in the PDF. I want can't find the controller used to handle the  **AdminPdf** and **generateDeliverySlipPDF**

```
    {if $order->delivery_number}
      <a class="btn btn-default _blank" href="{$link->getAdminLink('AdminPdf')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}&amp;submitAction=generateDeliverySlipPDF&amp;id_order={$order->id}">
      <i class="icon-truck"></i>
    </a>
   {/if}
```

Who can help me figure out the inside processes? I can't find the methods to handle generateDeliverySlipPDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AdminPdfController` is located at `/controllers/admin/AdminPdfController.php`.

The `submitAction=generateDeliverySlipPDF` part of the url will call the method `processGenerateDeliverySlipPDF()` inside this controller.

Here is this method:

```php
public function processGenerateDeliverySlipPDF()
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('id_order')) {
        $this->generateDeliverySlipPDFByIdOrder((int)Tools::getValue('id_order'));
    } elseif (Tools::isSubmit('id_order_invoice')) {
        $this->generateDeliverySlipPDFByIdOrderInvoice((int)Tools::getValue('id_order_invoice'));
    } elseif (Tools::isSubmit('id_delivery')) {
        $order = Order::getByDelivery((int)Tools::getValue('id_delivery'));
        $this->generateDeliverySlipPDFByIdOrder((int)$order->id);
    } else {
        die(Tools::displayError('The order ID -- or the invoice order ID -- is missing.'));
    }
}
```

In this Controller you'll find other methods as this one to generate Invoices, Order, ... and other PDFs.

Feel free to ask if you need more informations.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to change format in a proper way you'll have to override those classes:

`/override/classes/pdf/PDFGenerator.php`:

```php
<?php

/**
 * @since 1.5
 */
class PDFGenerator extends PDFGeneratorCore
{

    /**
     * @param bool $use_cache
     * @param string $orientation
     * @param string $format
     */
    public function __construct($use_cache = false, $orientation = 'P', $format = 'A4')
    {
        TCPDF::__construct($orientation, 'mm', $format, true, 'UTF-8', $use_cache, false);
        $this->setRTL(Context::getContext()->language->is_rtl);
    }
}
```

`/override/classes/pdf/PDF.php`:

```php
<?php

/**
 * @since 1.5
 */
class PDF extends PDFCore
{

    /**
     * @param $objects
     * @param $template
     * @param $smarty
     * @param string $orientation
     */
    public function __construct($objects, $template, $smarty, $orientation = 'P', $format = 'A4')
    {
        parent::__construct($objects, $template, $smarty, $orientation);
        $this->pdf_renderer = new PDFGenerator((bool)Configuration::get('PS_PDF_USE_CACHE'), $orientation, $format);
    }
}
```

`/override/controllers/admin/AdminPdfController.php`:

```php
<?php

class AdminPdfController extends AdminPdfControllerCore
{
    public function generatePDF($object, $template)
    {
        switch($template) {
            case PDF::TEMPLATE_DELIVERY_SLIP:
                $format = array(210, 50000); // Replace with your desired size
                break;
            default:
                $format = 'A4';
        }

        $pdf = new PDF($object, $template, Context::getContext()->smarty, 'P', $format);
        $pdf->render();
    }
}
```

Now you can specify the format for each PDF.
You will find informations about `$format` at [this place](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a134232ae3ad1ec186ed45046f94b7755)

This code has not been tested but should work as expected. Let me know if you encounter any issue.

You will need to delete `/cache/class_index.php` after adding those overrides to clear Prestashop internal classes path cache.

Comment: Hi, Do you how to customize the pager size when print the PDF in the pos roll paper?

Comment: If you're talking about page size and margins you can override the method `writePage()` inside `/classes/pdf/PDFGenerator.php`. This class extends the TCPDF library located in `/tools/tcpdf/tcpdf.php`.

Comment: Just to add to @FlorianLemaitre 's answer, each PDF generated has it's own class in /classes/pdf, for example, Delivery Slips are controlled by HTMLTemplateDeliverySlip.php. These assign variables and control some of the properties of the resulting PDF files, and also assign templates, of course. Also, remember to use overrides when modifying the `PDFGenerator` class - this will make your life a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: I an try to print in the Pos roll paper. The page break is annoying.  Is it possible to disable page break until it finished content.

Comment: @Eva I've edited my answer with a solution. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre Hi, about AdminPdfController class. Where was this class be called? As my understanding the origin project was called AdminPdfControllerCore. And I need to change it to AdminPdfController, right? It seemed AdminPdfController  never be called

Comment: It's a new class you have to create inside `override` folder. You can have a look at [Prestashop official override documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors)

Comment: You need to delete `/cache/class_index.php` after adding those overrides to clear Prestashop classes cache.

Comment: I did a little amend, I put the switch into PDF.php. So I don't need to override AdminPdfController.  Another thing might be much difficult. I am not sure if you got solution or not. I fixed the height of paper. If I want to adjust the page height according to the content. Do you get any idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109678/discussion-between-eva-and-florian-lemaitre).

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre: I'm overriding `AdminPdfController` in my module and adding a function that is simply calling `$this->generateDeliverySlipPDFByIdOrder($order_id);` Am I calling wrongly the generate PDF function ?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for this topic,

I would like to ask you for the case of generating pdf in front?

i.e
this is a part of  history.tpl

```
 `{if $order.details.invoice_url}
    <a href="{$order.details.invoice_url}"><i class="material-icons">&#xE415;</i></a>`
```

i found $order.details.invoice_url is define in OrderPresenter.php
and OrderPresenter use HistoryController to get the invoice_url.

So i take a look in historyController

```
if ((bool) Configuration::get('PS_INVOICE') && OrderState::invoiceAvailable($order->current_state) && count($order->getInvoicesCollection())) {
$url_to_invoice = $context->link->getPageLink('pdf-invoice', true, null, 'id_order='.$order->id);
            if ($context->cookie->is_guest) {
                $url_to_invoice .= '&amp;secure_key='.$order->secure_key;
            }
        }
```

getPageLink use "pdf-invoice"  ,i take a look for getPageLink Method and see that "pdf-invoice" is a controller...
the trouble is i don't know where is this controller?
 help please

Comment: This is not an answer, but adding to the problem.  for things like this it is best to add a comment to the existing question.