# How to get my PDF with a dynamic height? Or calculate the height of contents before it is printed

Tags: height, pdf-generation, prestashop-1.6

I noticed that in Prestashop, the printing out PDF action is set with certain page size, A4 or else. That includes the page width and height in advance. 
But, how I just set the width, and let the height be dependent on the contents? In a POS printer, I think many people may face with similar issues. Is there any way to calculate the height of contents before the PDF is generated? Thanks a million for any help!

BTW, prestashop is definitely a powerful template, you can learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at this solution. I got a perfect solution. [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720210/confused-about-prestashop-pdf-generated-process-where-is-the-code-to-handle-the/36721003?noredirect=1#comment61059274_36721003)